# How to get like count of a post by Post_id?

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it necessary to pass access token with the request?

Is there any other method of doing getting like count other than this

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{post-id}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: Why you need `other` method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to add access token preferrably collected and stored extended facebook access token I also not recommend using this by js rather php

because it violates security to have user access tokens in your js code